# What exactly is a front-end model?

Tags: software-design

Can someone provide a resource for learning what 'models' are in relation to a front-end application?

I understand models when it comes to a backend app -- just a data model that can be provided in, say, a response to a request from frontend.

BUT, for frontend, you have

- the data (model) from back end
- the actual data structure that the controller gives to the views, which often is an enhanced version of the backend model

So, when people say 'model', do they mean both?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: So, when people say 'model', do they mean both?

Yes.  A model is a model.  Based on some of your other questions, I suspect you're thinking of Angular models.  Here's a good explanation:

> https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/quickstart/domain-models/
>
> A good practice when writing Angular code is to try to isolate the
> data structures you are using from the component code.
>
> To solve this, let’s create a class is what we call a Domain Model,
> it’s just a plain class which we will use to store data and functions.